# F.conv2d stuck on my CentOS

Tags: centos, anaconda, pytorch

I run my pytorch code well on mac and even on windows system but the same code seems stuck on CentOS6.3.

I debug with ipdb, and found the code was stuck at F.conv2d function:

```
> /home/work/anaconda2/envs/PyTorch/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py(301)forward()
    300    return F.conv2d(input, self.weight, self.bias, self.stride,
--> 301        self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
    302 

ipdb> s
```

The running env was created with anaconda(python 2.7/3.6), pytorch version is 0.4.0.

I tried for a long time to resolve this problem and i tried. Do you have a suggestion? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstall CentOS6.3, and then upgrade glibc2.14, glibc2.17 due to the pytorch0.4.0 running error info.

Now everything is ok.

By the way, the pytorch0.3.1 perform well before i upgrade the glibc(up to 2.12). So i think the lastest pytorch0.4.0 may haven’t deal very well with glibc, leave running deadlock appearance and doesn’t tell any error and warning info, just stuck at F.conv2d in torch/nn/modules/conv.py(301).

See also: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/f-conv2d-stuck-on-my-centos/19794/3